# How restrict the view by members in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I just create a view for showing all registered members profile details. But the problem is admin can see all Member details and also Members can see only their details. Now i want to restrict the view by, Admin can see all members and the Member can see their details itself.

How i do it ?

And also i want create a privilege, for example Admin can see all details, Managers can see some restricted data and the Members also have some restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

If you use the content profile module, which creates a CCK content type for user information, you can use the content permissions built into CCK to restrict access to particular fields.

You could also in the view use a filter of "User:Current" which should filter the view to the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_perm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6) to create custom permissions.

```
<?php
  function mymodule_perm() {
    return array('View any members info', 'extra permissions ...');
  }
?>
```

Now you can set the View's access control to your custom permission.